# Install TeX Live 2021 on Windows 10 fails: No such file or directory

Tags: texlive, installing

One of my classmates experienced this error while installing TeX Live 2021:

```
Installing to: D:/texlive/2021
Installing [0001/4151, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: texlive.infra [424k]
Installing [0002/4151, time/total: 00:01/02:20:07]: texlive.infra.win32 [2695k]
open(>C:\Users\3\x{00c2}o\x{00c6}éa\AppData\Local\Temp\l0NWsP7YTv\vShqZ5MJpd/texlive.infra.win32.r57932.tar.xz) failed: No such file or directory at G://tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 1220, <STDIN> line 100.
```

He uses the ISO file for installation, under Windows 10 x64. He has tried to run `install-tl-windows.bat` with administrator rights, or to change the installation path to drive D, but none of these attempts can solve this error.

I suspect that the problem may lie in his username, which includes Chinese characters, but this cannot be modified by now.

What should he do about this?

Comment: write to the texlive list and ask for help ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer May I ask what is the "texlive list"?

Comment: https://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live

Answer (score 2):

Try the following: give from a command-prompt (cmd.exe; I do not know off-hand what would be the powershell equivalents):

```
md c:\texlive\temp
set TMP=c:\texlive\temp
D:\texlive\install-tl-windows.bat
```

If you want to install as administrator, this should be an administrative command-prompt.

This way, packages will be unpacked in a directory without chinese characters.

Normally, windows uses short directory names for TMP or TEMP, but I do not know what happens with chinese characters.